# ReferenceError: stops is not defined

Tags: google-sheets

Basically the Travelling Salesman Problem being solved by an idiot with no experience in coding. My problem right is this: ReferenceError: stops is not defined

```
    function myFunction() {

var df = Maps.newDirectionFinder();

df.setOrigin(String("Großaspacher Straße 10"));
df.setDestination(String("Weiherstraße 31"));

df.setMode(Maps.DirectionFinder.Mode.DRIVING);
df.setOptimizeWaypoints(true);

for(var i=0; i < stops.length; i++) {
    var addr = stops[i][0];     
    if(addr.length>0) {
        df.addWaypoint(addr);     
    }
}

var directions = df.getDirections();   
var stops_order = directions.routes[0].waypoint_order;

var stop_sequence=71;
for (j = 0; j < stops_order.length; j++) {
    var stop = stops_order.indexOf(j) + 1;
    stop_sequence.push([stop]);   
}

return stop_sequence; 
}


Error: ReferenceError: stops is not defined
```

and I don't get why.
Like I said, I have no idea what I'm doing, just trying to piece this together. So... thanks for any help

Comment: Somewhere in your code you use the variable `stops` and it is not defined. Could you attach your whole code?

Comment: too long for comments but I posted it

Comment: Kindly refrain from using answer as comment. You can edit your post above by click the `Edit` button below your post.

Comment: You didn't define the variable `stops`. You should have `var stops = source of data` in your code and the source of data should return 2 dimensional array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem:

- variable `stops` is undefined
- you want to use the data from sheets and assign it to variable `stops`
- you cannot push an element to `stop_sequence` because you defined it as integer in `var stop_sequence=71;`

### Solution:

- define a variable named `stops` and use the SpreadsheetApp Class to fetch data from spreadsheet
- change `var stop_sequence=71;` to `var stop_sequence=[];`

**Your code should look like this:**

```
function myFunction() {
  var df = Maps.newDirectionFinder();
  df.setOrigin(String("Großaspacher Straße 10"));
  df.setDestination(String("Weiherstraße 31"));
  df.setMode(Maps.DirectionFinder.Mode.DRIVING);
  df.setOptimizeWaypoints(true);

  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("insert sheetname here");
  //Example of range is A3:C3
  var stops = sheet.getRange("insert range here").getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < stops.length; i++) {
    var addr = stops[i][0];
    if (addr.length > 0) {
      df.addWaypoint(addr);
    }
  }
  var directions = df.getDirections();
  var stops_order = directions.routes[0].waypoint_order;
  var stop_sequence = [];
  for (j = 0; j < stops_order.length; j++) {
    var stop = stops_order.indexOf(j) + 1;
    stop_sequence.push([stop]);
  }
  return stop_sequence;
}
```

### Reference:

- [Class SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)

Comment: Thank you so much mate, I really really appreciate it. Ignore that last one, I was confusing spreadsheet and worksheet haha. But now it's telling me 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'waypoint_order' of undefined
How can I fix that?

Comment: It seems fine to me. Try printing the value of `directions.routes[0]` and check if there's a waypoint_order object in it. You can also change your declaration into : `var stops_order = directions.routes[0]["waypoint_order"];`

Comment: changing it doesn't immediately change the result, `TypeError: Cannot read property 'waypoint_order' of undefined `. And it won't log anything because I think it gets the error and then stops, so I can't print it I think?

Comment: You can start by adding `Logger.log(directions.routes[0]);` below `var directions = df.getDirections();`. This will print the value of `directions.routes[0]` to your editor. Also see [Troubleshooting your code in Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting)

Comment: Allright, so the Logger returns `Info   null`, debugging with a breakpoint at `var directions = df.getDirections();` spits out this [this](https://imgur.com/a/Okb7MLS). I'm not sure what to make of that?

Comment: I would like to support you but the issue now is a debugging matter and unrelated to the original post. It would be helpful if you create a separate post and discuss the current issue of your code. This will avoid confusion and the community can focus on the issue one at a time.